# Bootstrap 4 align Logo to the left, Center Menu and top links on the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am currently having trouble creating 2 rows and getting align logo(heading) to the left, 'Home' and 'User' menu links to the top right corner. The second row should display 'Link1', 'Link2', 'Link3' menu in the center. The following code doesn't seem to align properly.

I have tried to use 'navbar-nav mr-auto' for logo but it didn't work. Also tried 'Home', 'About' links 'ml-auto'. It doesn't work.

```
*******************************************************************************************
                                                                          Home About User
Logo Heading1                                                              

                          Link1  Link2 Link3 Link4
*******************************************************************************************

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="">
            <img style="width: 72px; height: 71px;" src="logo-1.png">Heading
        </a>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-wrap" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ace.aspx">Home</a>
                </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="About.aspx" >About</a>
            </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="User.aspx" >User</a>
            </li>

            </ul>

            <div id="divSubMenu" runat="server" >
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mt-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active" id="liDashboard" runat="server">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Dashboard.aspx">Link1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" id="liaint" runat="server">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="ation.aspx">Link2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" id="liign" runat="server">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" id="lise" runat="server">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Search.aspx">Link4</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try to use flex on your container in nav bar

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. hope will help You.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center mt-5">
      <li class="nav-item active" id="liDashboard" runat="server">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Dashboard.aspx">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="liaint" runat="server">
        <a class="nav-link" href="ation.aspx">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="liign" runat="server">
        <a class="nav-link">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="lise" runat="server">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Search.aspx">Link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav-item flex-row justify-content-md-center justify-content-start flex-nowrap">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mb-5">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="ace.aspx">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="About.aspx" >About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="User.aspx" >User</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo Heading1</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active" id="liDashboard" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="Dashboard.aspx">Link1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="liaint" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="ation.aspx">Link2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="liign" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link">Link3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="lise" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="Search.aspx">Link4</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="nav-item">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ace.aspx">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="About.aspx" >About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="User.aspx" >User</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If u want out put like you have provided text above logo above middle on below

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light align-items-start">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo Heading1</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mt-5">
                <li class="nav-item active" id="liDashboard" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="Dashboard.aspx">Link1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="liaint" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="ation.aspx">Link2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="liign" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link">Link3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="lise" runat="server">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="Search.aspx">Link4</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="nav-item">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ace.aspx">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="About.aspx" >About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="User.aspx" >User</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try stacking multiple navbars in bootstrap 4 as shown below. Please see if this answer is acceptable for you requirements. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Updated my code to only have two rows as requested in the question. Good luck champ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Stack Answer</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark py-0">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">User</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark pt-0">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img style="width: 72px; height: 71px;" src="http://placehold.it/72x71?text=Logo">
          Stack Answer
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Content -->


  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```